# ld: symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper not found, normally in crt1.o/dylib1.o/bundle1.o for architecture i386

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, makefile, pecl

I am installing mongo driver for php from source but experiencing an error when i run `make`

This is what i get:

`ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/bundle1.o, building for macOS-i386 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a, building for macOS-i386 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a, building for macOS-i386 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, missing required architecture i386 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
ld: symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper not found, normally in crt1.o/dylib1.o/bundle1.o for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mongo.la] Error 1`

i am using php `5.6` because the project i'm dealing with only supports `php5` with `mongo@3.4`. Any suggestions on how to get the driver installed please.

Mongo Driver : `http://pecl.php.net/get/mongo-1.6.16.tgz`

OS: `Mac OS Catalina`

Comment: how are you configuring your makefile?